# Rust regexes live long enough for match but not find

Tags: regex, rust

I'm trying to understand why behavior for the match regex is different from the behavior for find, from documentation [here](https://docs.rs/regex/latest/regex/#grouping-and-flags).

I have the following for match:

```rust
use regex::Regex;
```

```rust
{
let meow = String::from("This is a long string that I am testing regexes on in rust.");
let re = Regex::new("I").unwrap();

let x = re.is_match(&meow);
dbg!(x)
}
```

And get:

```
[src/lib.rs:142] x = true
```

Great, now let's identify the location of the match:

```rust
{
let meow = String::from("This is a long string that I am testing regexes on in rust.");
let re = Regex::new("I").unwrap();

let x = re.find(&meow).unwrap();
dbg!(x)
}
```

And I get:

```rust
let x = re.find(&meow).unwrap();
                ^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
}
^ `meow` dropped here while still borrowed
`meow` does not live long enough
```

I think I'm following the documentation.  Why does the string `meow` live long enough for a `match` but not long enough for `find`?

Comment: Please provide broader snippet. Code you currently showed compiles and works. In error message I see a closing bracket. Can you show that?

Comment: Sorry updated.  Both stanzas have brackets fully enclosing.  I'm running this in a jupyter notebook.

Comment: Here's a hunch: try adding a semicolon after printing: `dbg!(x);`

Comment: Thanks @kmdreko.  That did it.  Huh.  I'm very confused then why I /don't/ need a semicolon for the first case and it still works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing a value without `;` at the end of a `{ }` scope effectively returns that value out of the scope. For example:

```rust
fn main() {
    let x = {
        let y = 10;
        y + 1
    };

    dbg!(x);
}
```

```
[src/main.rs:7] x = 11
```

Here, because we don't write a `;` after the `y + 1`, it gets returned from the  inner scope and written to x.

If you write a `;` after it, you will get something different:

```rust
fn main() {
    let x = {
        let y = 10;
        y + 1;
    };

    dbg!(x);
}
```

```
[src/main.rs:7] x = ()
```

Here you can see that the `;` now prevents the value from being returned. Because no value gets returned from the inner scope, it implicitly gets the empty return type `()`, which gets stored in `x`.

---

The same happens in your code:

```rust
use regex::Regex;

fn main() {
    let z = {
        let meow = String::from("This is a long string that I am testing regexes on in rust.");
        let re = Regex::new("I").unwrap();

        let x = re.is_match(&meow);
        dbg!(x)
    };

    dbg!(z);
}
```

```
[src/main.rs:9] x = true
[src/main.rs:12] z = true
```

Because you don't write a `;` after the `dbg!()` statement, its return value gets returned from the inner scope. The `dbg!()` statement simply returns the value that gets passed to it, so the return value of the inner scope is `x`. And because `x` is just a bool, it gets returned without a problem.

Now let's look at your second example:

```rust
use regex::Regex;

fn main() {
    let z = {
        let meow = String::from("This is a long string that I am testing regexes on in rust.");
        let re = Regex::new("I").unwrap();

        let x = re.find(&meow).unwrap();
        dbg!(x)
    };

    dbg!(z);
}
```

```
error[E0597]: `meow` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:8:25
   |
4  |     let z = {
   |         - borrow later stored here
...
8  |         let x = re.find(&meow).unwrap();
   |                         ^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
9  |         dbg!(x)
10 |     };
   |     - `meow` dropped here while still borrowed
```

And now it should be more obvious what's happening: It's basically the same as the previous example, just that the returned `x` is now a type that internally borrows `meow`. And because `meow` gets destroyed at the end of the scope, `x` cannot be returned, as it would outlive `meow`.

The reason why `x` borrows from `meow` is because regular expression `Match`es don't actually copy the data they matched, they just store a reference to it.

So if you add a `;`, you prevent the value from being returned from the scope, changing the scope return value to `()`:

```rust
use regex::Regex;

fn main() {
    let z = {
        let meow = String::from("This is a long string that I am testing regexes on in rust.");
        let re = Regex::new("I").unwrap();

        let x = re.find(&meow).unwrap();
        dbg!(x);
    };

    dbg!(z);
}
```

```
[src/main.rs:9] x = Match {
    text: "This is a long string that I am testing regexes on in rust.",
    start: 27,
    end: 28,
}
[src/main.rs:12] z = ()
```

Comment: I think that find() is /internally/ borrowing /differently/ than `is_match` is a behavior I would not have expected and a really helpful thing for this answer to show me, so thoroughly.  Thanks for your answer, and I'm sorry the question is getting clobbered by closes and downvotes.

Comment: @Mittenchops You can see it [in the documentation](https://docs.rs/regex/latest/regex/struct.Regex.html#method.find): `pub fn find<'t>(&self, text: &'t str) -> Option<Match<'t>>`. The lifetime `'t` represents the borrowing of `text` in the return type.